# Issue with webscraping game data off of Metacritic

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm using `BeautifulSoup` to webscrape game data off of metacritic. I'm trying to get the scores and text for each reviewer. I thought that everything was going well but when I get the response back I see stuff like this:

```
class="c-siteReviewPlaceholder_header"
```

The site does not have the word placeholder in its classes. I know that I need to target the specific class:

```
class_="c-pageProductReviews_row"
```

So this is what my code looks like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.metacritic.com/game/alien-isolation/critic-reviews/? 
platform=playstation-4'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
       'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
       'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}
 critic_review_page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(critic_review_page.content, "html.parser")
 critic_review_rows = soup.find_all("div", class_="c-pageProductReviews_row")
 print(critic_review_rows)
```

When I print `critic_review_rows` I see a lot of the classes have the word placeholder in them. I don't know if Metacritic won't let me scrape the site or what is going on. It's almost as if the data is not loading the data by the time I'm scraping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue here is that the content is rendered dynamically by `javascript`, something that `requests` do not handle, because it is not acting like a browser and only work with the first static state of response.

The initial state is stored in script at the end of the page source, so you could extract it, but a better approach would be to use the api that is called:

```
import requests 

url = 'https://fandom-prod.apigee.net/v1/xapi/reviews/metacritic/critic/games/alien-isolation/platform/playstation-4/web?apiKey=1MOZgmNFxvmljaQR1X9KAij9Mo4xAY3u&offset=0&limit=50&sort=score&componentType=ReviewList'

requests.get(url).json()
```

---

```
{'data': {'id': 1400262756,
  'totalResults': 50,
  'items': [{'quote': 'The permanent threat of death keeps you forced to the ground – we can’t remember the last game where we willingly snuck around so much – and it feels like the claustrophobic corridors and catwalks of the Sevastopol were built from that angle. Being crouched, looking up at everything… it really does give you that feeling that Creative Assembly wanted it all along – that ‘prey being hunted’ effect. It makes a refreshing change from the feeling of being overpowered and able to kill anything that appears.',
    'score': 90,
    'url': 'http://www.play-mag.co.uk/reviews/ps4-reviews/alien-isolation-review-2/',
    'date': '2014-10-03',
    'author': None,
    'authorSlug': None,
    'image': None,
    'publicationName': 'Play UK',
    'publicationSlug': 'play-uk',
    'reviewedProduct': {'id': 1400262756,
     'type': 'games',
     'title': 'Alien: Isolation',
     'url': '/game/alien-isolation/',
     'criticScoreSummary': {'url': '/game/alien-isolation/critic-reviews/?platform=playstation-4',
      'score': 79},
     'platform': {'id': 1500000006, 'name': 'PlayStation 4'},
     'gameTaxonomy': {'game': {'id': 1400262756, 'name': 'Alien: Isolation'},
      'platform': {'id': 1500000006, 'name': 'PlayStation 4'}}},
    'platform': 'PlayStation 4'},...
```

Answer (score 1):

The data you see is on the page inside `<script>` element in the form Javascript. To parse some info about the reviews you can use e.g.:

```py
import re
from ast import literal_eval

import requests

url = "https://www.metacritic.com/game/alien-isolation/critic-reviews/?platform=playstation-4"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0"
}

html_text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

for q, s, u, d in re.findall(
    r'quote:"(.*?)",.*?score:(\d+).*?url:"(.*?)",.*?date:"(.*?)"', html_text
):
    print(s)
    print(q)
    print(literal_eval(f'"{u}"'))
    print(d)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
90
The permanent threat of death keeps you forced to the ground – we can’t remember the last game where we willingly snuck around so much – and it feels like the claustrophobic corridors and catwalks of the Sevastopol were built from that angle. Being crouched, looking up at everything… it really does give you that feeling that Creative Assembly wanted it all along – that ‘prey being hunted’ effect. It makes a refreshing change from the feeling of being overpowered and able to kill anything that appears.
http://www.play-mag.co.uk/reviews/ps4-reviews/alien-isolation-review-2/
2014-10-03
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
90
A masterwork of atmosphere and environmental design, Alien: Isolation may be standing on the shoulders of giants, but it's also one of the few franchise games to do so that doesn't topple off disastrously.
http://www.videogamer.com/reviews/alien_isolation_review.html
2014-10-03
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
90
It’s comfortably the best Alien game ever made, and delivers authenticity along with a new story that is worth seeing, experiencing, and fleeing from into the darkness. Never once allowing the immersion to be broken, Creative Assembly have done it. They have actually done it.
http://www.godisageek.com/2014/10/alien-isolation-review/
2014-10-03
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...
```

Comment: Thank you! Both these solutions worked and you beat out chatGPT! Thank you!